# How to generate two distinct sets of correlated ordinal variables?

Tags: r, simulation, structural-equation-modeling

I want to generate two distinct sets of correlated ordinal variables (ranging from 1 to 7). The first set will be represented by x1, x2 and x3 whereas the second set will be represented by x4, x5 and x6. I want the first set of variables (x1, x2 and x3) to be moderately correlated (e.g., 0.4) whereas the second set of variables (x4, x5 and x6) to be strongly correlated (e.g., 0.7). At the same time, I want the correlation between these two sets of variables to be weak (e.g., 0.10) with each other. I created the below function that gives me the six variables as I want, but I want to be able to specify the user-defined correlations in this function too. How can I get this done?

```
gen.df <- function(nvar, myscale=1:7, nobs=10, var_prefix = 'var'){
            out.df <- as.data.frame(replicate(nvar, 
              sample(myscale, nobs, replace=TRUE), simplify=FALSE))
            setNames(out.df, paste0(var_prefix, seq_along(out.df)))
           }
gen.df(nvar=6, myscale=1:7, nobs=20)
```

Comment: What measure of correlation do you wish to use?

Comment: Pearson for this example.

Comment: Pearson's coefficient does not make sense for purely ordinal variables.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I thought for this example Pearson would serve the purpose. Will it be possible to use polychoric correlations?

Comment: What correlations do you want to specify? You want to generate ordinal variables with a specific correlation. Polychoric? If so you also need to specify thresholds.

Comment: The correlations among the ordinal indicators/variables! For instance, the user of the function will be able to decide the size of the correlations among the ordinal variables for every generation. I hope this makes sense. I want to create this function for pedagogical purposes, generating random variables to run different CFA/SEM models.

Comment: I would create continuous variables (you can use the mvrnorm() function in the MASS package) and then if you want ordinal use the cut() function.

Comment: Thanks, Jeremy. This was useful.